# My program doesn't have any syntax errors but just wont do what its meant to (Python)

Tags: python

```
import random
import time
print ("Welcome to 'Project X'")
print ("----------------------")
login = input("Please enter your username:")
time.sleep(1)
print ("Please wait...")
time.sleep(1)
print ("Generating randomized password")
password = random.randint(1000000000, 9000000000)
time.sleep(3)
print ("This is your randomized password:", password)
print ("Write down your password, you have 10 seconds")
time.sleep(10)
import os
os.system("cls")
login2 = input("Please enter your username:")
if login2 == login:
    password2 = input("Please enter your password:")
    if password2 == password:
        print ("Access Granted, Welcome Mr.", login)
        time.sleep(2)
        ipaddress = input("Enter an ip address you want to ping:")
        print ("Processing ip address...")
        time.sleep(2)
        os.system("ping ", ipaddress)
    elif password2 != password:
        print ("Access Denied")
        print ("Sending S.W.A.T Team")
        time.sleep(2)
        print ("...")
        time.sleep(2)
        print ("Shutting down systems...")
        os.system("cls")
else:
    print ("Access Denied")
    print ("Sending S.W.A.T Team")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("Shutting down systems...")
    os.system("cls")
```

I want it find out why it doesn't run the rest of the code when it comes to entering the password again, even though its right it still says access denied and goes through the process of the other commands.

Comment: "...when it comes to entering the password again" - I see only one place in the code for entering the pwd. Where exactly does the user have to enter the pwd *again* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following line generate an `int`

```
password = random.randint(1000000000, 9000000000)
```

Then you ask for a `str` input with

```
password2 = input("Please enter your password:")
```

This comparison will always be false

```
if password2 == password:
#  ^str         ^int
```

You have to compare the same type, so for example

```
if int(password2) == password:
#  ^int              ^int
```

Or convert the input on the way in

```
password2 = int(input("Please enter your password:"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer it helped yet when I enter an ip address it gives me an error, is this because I may of entered an incorrect ip address or is it wrong?

Comment: IP addresses aren't integers since they have multiple `.` characters in them.

Comment: I havent put the ipaddress variable as an integer ive kept it the same

Comment: so when you input the ipaddress it will be entered as a string

Answer (score 0):

`random.randint(1000000000, 9000000000)` returns an `int`. `input("Please enter your password:")` returns a `str`. Use `int(input("Please enter your password:"))`.